# How to display only the first image out of an array of images rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the index page of my app, i want to display only the first image of a post that has multiple images attached to it.

```
<% (0...job.images.count).each do |image| %>

<%= image_tag(job.images[image]) %>

<% end %>
```

I have tried:

```
<%= image_tag job.images.first.try[image] %>
```

But get a no method given error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the first bit of code you've provided, you should be able to use this:

```
<%= image_tag job.images.first %>
```

Assuming that `job.images` is an array of paths to the images?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to treat it as a normal ActiveRecord query

```
<%= image_tag job.images.first if job.images.attached? %>
```